# Selenium issue timeout with any request after a login

Tags: python, selenium

I'm developing a script that login in a web page and then do a lot of things. The webapge is [ML](http://www.mercadolibre.com.uy/). I login without any problem with the following code :

```
 def login_ml(self, user, password):

    self.driver.get(self.main_url)

    # li that contains the login
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@id="login"]/a').click()
    self.wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("modal-iframe"))

    self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "user_id"))).send_keys(user)
    self.driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(password)
    self.driver.find_element_by_id('signInButton').click()
    time.sleep(5)
```

This page have a lot of AJAX, is for this that i set this :

```
self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20)
```

When the login process finished nothing else work fine, take too long everything you do it, for example if I try to change to the following page:

```
self.driver.get('http://www.google.com')
```

Take 10 or 15 min aprox.

Or this :

```
 item = self.driver.find_element_by_id('account')
 item.click()
```

I don't know how to do, I change to CSS Selectors, Xpath, by ID and everything fails. Is like this page freeze all. I try with other pages with AJAX and work fine, my problem I think is this page. I use a proxy to my connection. Please if somebody can help me.

Comment: What happens if you remove WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20)?  Normally, WebDriver waits will wait for a conditional to be satisfied, such as WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//somelement))